# How do I apply style to a Blazor InputSelect component?

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

I created custom multiple InputSelect component named "InputSelectRoles". And I want use class "test" for adding some css styles. I created file InputSelectRoles.razor.css and add styles for my class. But it doesn't work. If I add "form-control" class everything is good for example, styles added for component, but any others don't work.

This is InputSelectRoles.razor code:

```
@using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis
@inherits InputBase<string[]>

<InputSelect TValue="string[]" class="test" @bind-Value="HandleChange">
    @ChildContent
    @foreach (string role in Constants.Roles.Items)
    {
        <option value="@role">@role</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    public string[] HandleChange
    {
        get { return this.CurrentValue; }
        set { this.CurrentValue = value; }
    }

    protected override bool TryParseValueFromString(string value, [MaybeNullWhen(false)] out string[] result, [NotNullWhen(false)] out string validationErrorMessage)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

And this is my css file InputSelectRoles.razor.css:

```
.test {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

The problem is only with InputSelect component. Style works with  etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InputSelectRoles.razor.css` file will only affect the style of the raw HTML content present in your `InputSelectRoles.razor`.

For example, in this code:

```
<InputSelect TValue="string[]" class="test" @bind-Value="HandleChange">
    @ChildContent
    @foreach (string role in Constants.Roles.Items)
    {
        <option value="@role">@role</option>
    }
</InputSelect>
```

Only this line will be affected by your CSS.
What you can do:

- Try to use the ::deep keywork, as explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0 (I do not know if it works well now)
- Put your style in a  tag in your Razor file
- Put your style in the global CSS file of your project